# How can I save a file into appbundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, app-bundle

I have an image named `my-image`. Can I save this image to the application bundle? If yes, can you provide me the code or paths.

As of now, I have the following code –

```
NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userSavedImage); //convert image into .png format.
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
NSString * fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",txtImageName.text]]; //add our image to the path

[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the image

NSLog(@"image saved");
```

However it is saving in

```
/Users/tsplmac01/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/BC5DE1D8-B875-44BC-AC74-04A17329F29A/.
```

& not in the application bundle. Please tell me how I can do it.

Comment: Hey Sharmain, did u even consider searching for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in writing to a file in application bundle.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564153/problem-in-writing-to-a-file-in-application-bundle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The app bundle is read only for the app, so it is not possible to write to it.

This is a good restriction, because it would otherwise be wiped out when the app gets updated. You may want to write to the documents directory instead.